# SQL expression that adds a column from arithmetic on two other columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table:

```
_________________________________
| Student | Competitions | Wins |
_________________________________
| Johnny  |     8        |  4   |
| Michael |     9        |  4   |
| Ariel   |     5        |  3   |
| Raphael |     5        |  1   |
```

I would like to create a new table that adds a new column containing the win percentage of each student. Like this:

```
__________________________________________
| Student | Competitions | Wins | Win Pct |
__________________________________________
| Johnny  |     8        |  4   |   .5    |
| Michael |     9        |  4   |   .44   |
| Ariel   |     5        |  3   |   .6    |
| Raphael |     5        |  1   |   .2    |
```

Is there any way to do this - i.e. to create a new column by dividing the value in one column by the value in another?

Comment: Did you try writing a query that divides the two columns?  What database are you using?

Comment: Wny not just create a view if this value is always calculated?

Answer (score 2):

How about just adding an expression as another field in your SELECT clause, like so:

```
SELECT Student, Competitions, Wins, Wins / Competitions 
FROM tablename
```

Comment: This is much better than adding a column. You shouldn't store calculated values.

Comment: Cool - I didn't realize it was that simple!!

Comment: I unaccepted the answer because I found a problem with the answer - the results in the new column are only zero or one. I think this may have something to do with needing to specify that it becomes a float... how do I do this? Can you update your answer?

Comment: See answer from SamShin below.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, what you are doing is bad. A database should store basic information--here, data like Student, Competitions, and Wins. A win percentage, on the other hand, can change based on the other data. It's derived from both Competitions and Wins, and so should be computed every time it's needed. There are, of course, performance considerations for especially complex derived columns, but this shouldn't be a concern in your case.

For a rough analogy, think about why storing a user's age in a database is a poor design decision when you already have their birth date.

Comment: That's exactly why I want a query that will allow me to recalculate it whenever I want

Comment: Then see SamShin's answer above. You can very simply calculate this every time you need it, rather than having it saved in a table just waiting to get stale.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to agree with the other answers, that this is a bad design practice as you're storing basic calculated data.

That being said..this query should do it for you (assuming, you've already created the column)

`update tablename set WinPct = (coalesce(Wins,0)/Competitions) where Competitions IS NOT NULL`

This should cleanly support null values (NULL competitions => Null WinPct).

You'd have to set triggers (or use application logic) to repopulate this field everytime Wins or Comps are updated, but I'll skip that part of it. This is another reason why storing this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

mti2935 is right, the only change is adding  ' * 1.0' this will convert int to float

SELECT Student, Competitions, Wins, Wins * 1.0 / Competitions 
FROM tablename